# Python Unicode Ascii, Ordinal not In range, frustrating error

Tags: python, unicode

Here is my problem...

Database stores everything in unicode.
hashlib.sha256().digest() accepts str and returns str.

When I try to stuff hash function with the data, I get the famous error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is my data

```
>>> db_digest
u"'\x90\x017~1\xe0\xaf4\xf2\xec\xd5]:j\xef\xe6\x80\x88\x89\xfe\xf7\x99,c\xff\xb7\x06hXR\x99\xad\x91\x93lM:\xafT\xc9j\xec\xc3\xb7\xea[\x80\xe0e\xd6\\\xd8\x16'\xcb6\xc8\xaa\xdf\xc9 :\xff"
>>> 
>>> hashlib.sha256(db_digest)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x90' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> 
>>> asc_db_digest
"'\x90\x017~1\xe0\xaf4\xf2\xec\xd5]:j\xef\xe6\x80\x88\x89\xfe\xf7\x99,c\xff\xb7\x06hXR\x99\xad\x91\x93lM:\xafT\xc9j\xec\xc3\xb7\xea[\x80\xe0e\xd6\\\xd8\x16'\xcb6\xc8\xaa\xdf\xc9 :\xff"
>>> hashlib.sha256(asc_db_digest)
<sha256 HASH object @ 0x7f7da0f04300>
```

So all I am asking for is a way to turn db_digest into asc_db_digest

**Edit**
I have rephrased the question as it seems I haven't recognized teh problem correctly at first place.

Comment: It would be nice to know *why* hex or base64 is not an option, as it is the best way. P.S. Did you see the second part of my answer?

Comment: @MarkRansom I just rephrased the question entirely. see inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a unicode string that only contains code points from 0 to 255 (bytes) you can convert it to a Python str using the raw_unicode_escape encoding:

```
>>> db_digest = u"'\x90\x017~1\xe0\xaf4\xf2\xec\xd5]:j\xef\xe6\x80\x88\x89\xfe\xf7\x99,c\xff\xb7\x06hXR\x99\xad\x91\x93lM:\xafT\xc9j\xec\xc3\xb7\xea[\x80\xe0e\xd6\\\xd8\x16'\xcb6\xc8\xaa\xdf\xc9 :\xff"
>>> hash_digest = "'\x90\x017~1\xe0\xaf4\xf2\xec\xd5]:j\xef\xe6\x80\x88\x89\xfe\xf7\x99,c\xff\xb7\x06hXR\x99\xad\x91\x93lM:\xafT\xc9j\xec\xc3\xb7\xea[\x80\xe0e\xd6\\\xd8\x16'\xcb6\xc8\xaa\xdf\xc9 :\xff"
>>> db_digest.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
"'\x90\x017~1\xe0\xaf4\xf2\xec\xd5]:j\xef\xe6\x80\x88\x89\xfe\xf7\x99,c\xff\xb7\x06hXR\x99\xad\x91\x93lM:\xafT\xc9j\xec\xc3\xb7\xea[\x80\xe0e\xd6\\\xd8\x16'\xcb6\xc8\xaa\xdf\xc9 :\xff"
>>> db_digest.encode('raw_unicode_escape') == hash_digest
True
```

Answer (score 3):

hashes operates on bytes (`bytes`, `str` in Python 2.x), not strings (`unicode` in 2.x, `str` in 3.x). Therefore, you must supply bytes anyways. Try:

```
hashlib.sha1(salt.encode('utf-8') + data).digest()
```

Comment: `salt.encode('utf-8') != salt` hence, it will fail at matching. `hexdigest` is not an option either, all I need is a way to turn `db_digest` into `hash_digest` (vars in my question)

Comment: @TzuryBarYochay then you need to find out what encoding is used for the salt in the database.

Answer (score 1):

The hash will contain "characters" that are in the range 0-255. These are all valid Unicode characters, but it's not a Unicode string. You need to convert it somehow. The best solution would be to encode it into something like [base64](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html?highlight=base64#base64).

There's also a hacky solution to convert the bytes returned directly into a pseudo-Unicode string, exactly as your database appears to be doing it:

```
hash_unicode = u''.join([unichr(ord(c)) for c in hash_digest])
```

You can also go the other way, but this is more dangerous as the "string" will contain characters outside of the ASCII range of 0-127 and might throw errors when you try to use it.

```
asc_db_digest = ''.join([chr(ord(c)) for c in db_digest])
```